# How use block with enumerable in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, enumerable

How use enumerable in erb (rails views) with block. for example:

```
<% <% @schedules.select do |s| s.class_room == 10 %>
  <%= s.class_room %>
<% end %> %>
```

I want select record where field `class_room` equal `10`. how i can do this in the erb???

Comment: I think this logic could be better a method providing an own instance variable within the controller.

Comment: You should consider using `Schedule.where(class_room: 10)` which will filter the results in the database instead of pulling everything out and then filtering it in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some `<%` and `%>` extra, but this might work:

```
<% @schedules.select { |schedule| schedule.class_room == 10 }.each do |schedule| %>
  <%= schedule.class_room %>
<% end %>
```

First line just select those schedules where `class_room` in is 10 in one line, then opens a multi line block, and in a new line you use `<%= %>` to open each schedule `class_room`.

---

Alternatively you can pass to the next element during the iteration `unless` the `schedule.class_room` is 10:

```
<% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
  <% next unless schedule.class_room == 10 %>
  <%= schedule.class_room %>
<% end %>
```